# Mongodb sum the size of array fields

Tags: mongodb

so i have a bunch of simple documents like

```
{

  "foos": [
    ObjectId("5105862f2b5e30877c685c58"),
    ObjectId("5105862f2b5e30877c685c57"),
    ObjectId("5105862f2b5e30877c685c56"),
  ],

  "typ": "Organisation",

}
```

and i want to find out the overall size of associated `foos` to documents of type "Organisation"

so i have this aggregate query

```
db.profil.aggregate(
   [
   {
    $match:{
     "typ":"Organisation"
    }
   },
      {
         $project: {
            fooos: { $size: "$foos" }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

this returns the count of all foos for each document

like :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50e577602b5e05e74b38a6c8"), "foooos" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51922170975a09f363e3eef5"), "foooos" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51922170975a09f363e3eef8"), "foooos" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5175441d975ae346a3a8dff2"), "foooos" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5192216f975a09f363e3eee9"), "foooos" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5192216f975a09f363e3eeeb"), "foooos" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5192216f975a09f363e3eee4"), "foooos" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5192216f975a09f363e3eee6"), "foooos" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5192216f975a09f363e3eedb"), "foooos" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51922174975a09f363e3ef4a"), "foooos" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5192216f975a09f363e3eee1"), "foooos" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5192216e975a09f363e3eed7"), "foooos" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5192216f975a09f363e3eeee"), "foooos" : 3 }
```

is there some query that would return the summed up count for foos of all documents ?

i played arround with $sum but dont know how to combine with my query, i only do get syntax errors, it would be cool to know if this is possible

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Include the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator pipeline stage after the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) step as follows:

```
db.profil.aggregate([
   { "$match":{ "typ": "Organisation" } },
   { "$project": {
         "fooos": { "$size": "$foos" }
   } },
   { "$group": {
       "_id": null,
       "count": {
           "$sum": "$fooos"
       }
   } }
])
```

This will group all the input documents from the previous [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage and applies the accumulator expression [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) on the `fooos` field within the group to get the total (using your last example):

This can also be done by-passing the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) pipeline as:

```
db.profil.aggregate([
   { "$match": { "typ": "Organisation" } },
   { "$group": {
       "_id": null,
        "count": {
            "$sum": { "$size": "$foos" }
        }
    } }
])
```

**Output**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "count" : 24
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Please note that the `_id` field isn't necessary.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Thanks for noting that.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot it works like a charme ! i needed to include `"foos":{$ne:null}` to the $match query to put it to work

Comment: @johnSmith Nice one! Glad it all worked out for you in the end

Comment: More longer than : 
`aggregate([ { "$match": { "typ": "Organisation" } }, { $group: { _id: "", "total": {$sum: {$size: "$foos"}}}}]`

Answer (score 17):

I know this is an old question but you can bypass project altogether if you want, so how about this?

```
db.profil.aggregate([
{
    "$match":{ "typ": "Organisation" }
},
{
    "$group":
    {
        "_id": null,
        "count":
        {
            "$sum": { "$size": "$foos" }
        }
    }
}])
```

The output remains the same and it seems it's (slightly) faster.