# how to aggregate the sum of the jsonarray sizes in Collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have Collection in MongoDB and each document in the collection in below form

{
  "record":"A",
  "samples":[
             "a",
             "b",
             "c"]
}
{
  "record":"B",
  "samples":[
             "s",
             "t",
             "u",
             "v",
             "w"]
}

Please help with query that can be executed in mongodb to get the total count of samples in the entire collection

In this example: 3+5 = 8

Comment: Try `db.col.aggregate({$group:{_id:null, count:{$sum:{"$size:"$samples"}}}})`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongodb sum the size of array fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236495/mongodb-sum-the-size-of-array-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your document "sample" in an array so you first need to use `$unwind` to deconstruct the elements.

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
    { $unwind : "$samples" },
    { $group : { _id : "sample", count: {$sum:1} }}
])
```

output:

```
{
    "_id" : "sample",
    "count" : 8.0
}
```